# In excel can anyone show me how to concatenate strings and variables to make a cell reference?

Tags: excel, string, concatenation, formula

If I manually reference a cell in another spreadsheet (by typing `=` in the destination cell and then clicking in the source spreadsheet), excel creates a formula like this: `='H:\excel\data\[source_file.xls]Sheet1'!$C$5`

I am wanting to create that formula from the cell and path which are stored in cells in the destination spreadsheet (and some strings).

So I have in 3 cells `B1:B3` in the destination spreadsheet these strings:

`H:\excel\data\`

`source_file.xls`

`Sheet1!$c$5`

Then, so far, I have placed this formula in the cell where I want the data from the source spreadsheet:
`=B1&"["&B2&"]"&B3`

Which evaluates to:
`H:\excel\data\[source_file.xls]Sheet1!$c$5`

Pretty close to what I need. But as you can see some single quotes are missing. If I try to put these in, excel seems to think I am giving it a defined name.

Is there perhaps some sort of escape character I should put before the quote to make it work?

I have searched this website and excel help files to no avail.

That is the end of the question but I anticipate that someone is going to ask me why I am doing this. Well I want to automatically pluck values from a directory full of spreadsheets (which all have the same format)the value of one cell from each.

I had tried to do it using the advice found here:
http://www.ashishmathur.com/extract-data-from-multiple-cells-of-closed-excel-files/

Unfortunately, I was only able to get the first step to work (create a list of filenames of the files in the source directory). The remaining steps are not possible because my employer does not allow downloading of add-ins for security reasons (it is a hospital).

So I thought the approach outlines above might work but I can't quite make it happen!

Thanks

Mike A

Comment: So is B3 would need to be `Sheet1'!$C$5` to add the `'` in correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDIRECT()

```
=INDIRECT("'" & B1 & "[" & B2 & "]" & B3)
```

As stated in the comments the `'` would need to added to B3, so the input is `Sheet1'!$C$5`.

You may want to split the sheet name from the cell address then you could do:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & B1 & "[" & B2 & "]" & B3 & "'!" & B4)
```

Where B3 is only the sheet name and B4 the cell address.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that is brilliant. I had thought incorrectly that indirect only worked in a single workbook.